# How to customize firebase push notification message on IOS client

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have built push notification triggered by Firebase database change. Everything is working fine. However, I want to customize message on client side.

Is there any way to customize Firebase push notification message on the app programming?

Comment: In addition, I am using xcode10 and swift 4.2

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

Comment: What kind of notification? Is it from [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) or something else?